# Under what circumstances _buckets[bucketNumber].key == _buckets && ((_buckets[bucketNumber].hash_coll & unchecked(0x80000000)) == 0)) in Hashtable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, base-class-library

https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Hashtable.cs
[image: code]

Under what conditions will this logic be executed that `_buckets[bucketNumber].key == _buckets && ((_buckets[bucketNumber].hash_coll & unchecked(0x80000000)) == 0))`

The key is set to _buckets when that bucket once contained an entry and it is a collision in Remove

Comment: That's rather hard to tell without reading the full code which I'm honestly too lazy to do. The source code for this class is also on GitHub and has [unit tests](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/79ae74f5ca5c8a6fe3a48935e85bd7374959c570/src/libraries/System.Collections.NonGeneric/tests/HashtableTests.cs). You could try setting a breakpoint there and debug them. You could also ask your question [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions).

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comment it's pretty clear: if the bucket exists and has no other value inside (ie if it was never used), or if there was a single value (no collision) and was later removed, thus leaving the bucket empty.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but in Remove _buckets[bn].key will be null when no collision.
I can not find any case that  _buckets[bucketNumber].key == _buckets  when no collision once [link](https://lulianqi.com/file/removefun.png)